# python : how to get absolute path for a parent dir

Tags: python, path, glob

I have a file at location `a/b/c/d/e/f/x.xml` . i need to find the absolute path of the the dir `d`, i.e a parent dir up the hierarchy that matches the dir name `d` .

I can obtain the filename's current dir as `os.path.abspath(__file__)` . i have see the documentation for [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) and [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob), but am unable to figure out how would i use them.

Can someone help

EDIT:

Thanks to all the answers below, I have gotten to a one liner

```
os.path.join(*list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != 'd', pathlib.PurePath(os.getcwd()).parts)))
```

I also need to append the actual dir name to it, i.e, the output should be `a/b/c/d` . An ugly solution is below (uses os.path.join twice). Can someone fix it (by adding an element to the iterator or to the list in one line :)

```
os.path.join(os.path.join(*list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != 'd', pathlib.PurePath(os.getcwd()).parts))),"d")
```

Answer (score 2):

You use can use `dirname` on `abspath` of `__file__` to get the **full path** of the x.xml:

`os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> p = pathlib.PurePath('a/b/c/d/e/f/x.xml')
>>> p.parts
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'x.xml')
```

Then you can extract any part of your path. If you want to get the `d` folder:

```
import itertools
res = '/'.join(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != 'd', p.parts))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pathlib`'s [`Path.resolve()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) and [`Path.parents`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parents):

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("a/b/c/d/e/f/x.xml").resolve()

for parent in path.parents:
    if parent.name == "d":  # if the final component is "d", the dir is found
        print(parent)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp and cut:

```
import re
import os
mydir_regexp = re.compile('dirname')
abs_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
s = re.search(mydir_regexp, abs_path)

my_match = abs_path[:abs_path.index(s.group())+len(s.group())]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a file in your current dir, you can get it absolute path (starting at root) with `abspath`:

```
path = os.path.abspath(filename)
```

Thes the magic word is `os.path.split` that splits a pathname into the last component and the head (everything in front of it). So to get the absolute path of what comes before `d` just iterate the components:

```
def findinit(path, comp):
    while (len(path) > 1):
        t = os.path.split(path)
        if t[1] == comp:
            return t[0]
        path = t[0]
    return None
```

You can control that `findinit('/a/b/c/d/e/f/x.xml')` gives as expected `/a/b/c`

---

Alternatively if you want to use the `pathlib` module, you can search the `parts` for a specific component:

```
def findinit(path, comp):
    p = pathlib.PurePath(path)
    i = p.parts.index(comp)
    if i != -1:
        return pathlib.PurePath(*p.parts[:i])
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the one-liner finally:

```
os.path.join(*list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != 'd', pathlib.PurePath(os.getcwd()).parts)),"d")
```

wouldnt hve been possible without others answers though. thanks a lot.