# How to get the parent directory with fsspec?

Tags: python, fsspec

Given a filepath, how do I obtain the parent directory containing the file using `fsspec` ? Filepath can be using local filesystem or cloud storage, that's why `fsspec` is prefered.

Comment: Is there any documentation available for this?

Answer (score 1):

`fsspec` implements file system operations, while paths are just strings. So, you don't need `fsspec` to manipulate paths. You can use [Path.resolve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) or simply [os.path.abspath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath), and these don't require access to the file system itself. For example:

```
>>> os.path.abspath("/foo/bar/..")
'/foo'
```

If you need to verify if the resolved parent path actually exists, this is where you'd use [fsspec.spec.AbstractFileSystem.exists](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=exists#fsspec.spec.AbstractFileSystem.exists) which will actually make a request to the underlying file system.

See also this question: [python : how to get absolute path for a parent dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904428/python-how-to-get-absolute-path-for-a-parent-dir)

Answer (score 1):

@Timur is correct in paths just being strings, and you are welcome to manipulate them directly.

However, any filesystem also implements a `_parent` class method, which will give you a normalised version of the parent directory (normalised meaning stripping the protocol and host, converting windows to posix, etc, and can in principle be backend-dependent).

```
fs = fsspec.filesystem("s3")
parent = fs._parent("s3://bucket/prefix/path")
assert parent == "bucket/prefix"
```

We also intend to implement a filesystem `.path` attribute to provide convenience os.path-like functions specialised to the filesystem in question.